# Find Radiobutton Control from ID String in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, session-variables

I have 3 radiobuttons in my aspx:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoMasculin" 
     runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
     Checked="true" GroupName="gender" 
     TextAlign="Right" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoFeminin" 
     runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
     GroupName="gender" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoAnonymous" 
     runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
     GroupName="gender" />
```

When sending the form I'm storing the `ID` of the checked radiobutton in a Session variable:

for example: `Session("currentGender") = rdoZukuTermine.ID`

When I'm getting back on the page in a later stage I'm using the following code in codebehind:

```
Dim currentRadio = CType(FindControl(Session("currentGender")), RadioButton)
currentRadio.Checked = True
Session.Remove("currentGender")
```

`currentRadio` ends up as a null reference. But when I'm checking the Session it contains the right ID as a string. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the RadioButton control directly in your .aspx or does it have any parent controls? if yes call Findcontrol() on it direct parent like this:

```
Dim currentRadio = CType(ParentControl.FindControl(Session("currentGender")), RadioButton)
```

Comment: yes I have the radiobuttons in a placeholder, I used your suggestion and now it works perfectly. Thx :)